# how to calculate the sum of the first 100 integers in MySQL with a while loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop, sum, do-while

I must find the sum of the first 100 natural numbers. 1+2+3+...+n, and so on. While using "while loops".

```
delimiter $

create procedure `calcul`.somme()

begin

declare s int default 0;
declare i int default 1;

while(i<=100) do
    set s := s+i;
    set i := i+1;
end while;
select s;

end;
$
call `calcul`.somme()
```

when I call the somme() I'm getting this error -->

`call calcul.somme()= Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: Use not WHILE but REPEAT .. UNTIL i < 100. PS. `set i := i=1;` - must be `+1`.

Comment: No need for a loop. `SELECT 5050;`

Comment: `SET @i=100; SELECT (@i+1)*@i/2;` will be another choice for you

Comment: @lucumt - its obviously an assignment on using while loops.

Comment: @wiamleo - Whats the problem ?

Comment: @RohitGupta  not working when I call the somme() I'm getting this error -->
call calcul.somme()= Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: btw You haven't reset the delimiter after the create..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use calcul;
delimiter $
create procedure somme()
begin


declare s int default(0);
declare i int default(1);

    while(i<=100) do
    set s := s+i;
    set i := i+1;
    end while;
select s;
end;
$
CALL somme()
```

thanks, the Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The query is taking too long and the engine is timing out.

You can edit the SQL Editor preferences in MySQL Workbench:

1. In the application menu, select Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor.
2. Look for the MySQL Session section and increase the DBMS connection read time out value.
3. Save the settings, quite MySQL Workbench and reopen the connection.

Comment: Emm same error , the sum doesn't work

Comment: Did you find the setting, try at least 6000, and did you reopen the connection?  Maybe try restarting mysql.

Comment: 'wiam leo' - try to be more specific- are you saying the connection issue is still there or the procedure does not produce the correct outcome and please confirm you amended to set i := i+1;  nb loops are slow.. cut down to 10 check it works then push up to required limit better still parameterise.